# Microsoft ODBC for Oracle not working in excel vba

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I am trying to connect to oracle database using the odbc method from excel vba 2010. I am going to this approach since I want to establish a tns less connection.

I developed a below code.

```
Private Sub cb_getExecutionPlanName_Click()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim connString As String
Dim rsRecords As ADODB.Recordset

connString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=    (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=**))); uid=***; pwd=***;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsRecords = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open connString    // <<< Error thrown here

 rsRecords.Open "select name as name from w_etl_defn where inactive_flg = 'N';", conn

 i = 0
 With Me.ListBox1
  .Clear
  Do
    .AddItem
    .List(i, 0) = rsRecords!Name
    i = i + 1
    rsRecords.MoveNext
     Loop Until rsRecords.EOF
 End With

 rsRecords.Close
 Set rsRecords = Nothing
 conn.Close
 Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

However I am getting automation error while opening the connection. Error details are given below:

> Run time Error '-2147467259(80004005);'
>
> ```
> Automation Error
> Unspecified Error
> ```

Why is the highlighted line throwing this error?

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what you are asking here and if you can narrow down the line of code throwing the error we might be able to help you answer of the form `Why does this line of code throw an automation error?`

Comment: conn.Open connString

Comment: conn.Open connString statement throws automation error. It is the problem

Comment: Do you have the Oracle client installed? have you tested the connection from Oracle tools and from ODBC?

Comment: Which Oracle Client do you have installed? 32 bit or 64 bit? Excel is a 32 bit application, thus the Oracle Client must be also 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are protecting your host names, passwords and the like.  However, you need to take your connection string and make sure that it works with

```
sqlplus myuser/mypassword@`(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=**)))'
```

If this fails then your sqlnet string is bad or your password and user are bad.  You could just rely on the tns_names.ora file or other files in installed client's network/admin directory simplify the string to say @myservice_or_sid.

@ElectricLlama  makes a good point. If you are using the MS Client for Oracle verses Oracle ODBC driver, then you will run into a world of hurt with other Oracle database objects.

Comment: I was under the impression that the MS client doesn't even work without the Oracle client installed.

Comment: `connString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};`  The problem I've seen is that the MS client also doesn't know how to handle Oracle's overloaded function and procedure name use.

Comment: where do I use this sqlplus... code? And do I need a reference library installed before Excel VBA can execute this?

Comment: @Ammar Naseer there are several ways to connect to an Oracle database. sqlplus comes with an Oracle "client" installation on your work station.  All you are trying to do with sqlplus is to make sure that you can connect to the database if Excel VBA is your preferred database access method.  The ideas is just like a "Hello World" program.  A Hello World program is used to make sure that you can compile the simple program that you write.  Since sqlplus is command line tool, it is often used in automation scripts to work on data without a GUI.